# PHP: How to Pass child class __construct() arguments to parent::__construct()?

Tags: php, inheritance, constructor

I have a class in PHP like so:

```
class ParentClass {
    public function __construct($arg) {
        // Initialize a/some variable(s) based on $arg
    }
}
```

It has a child class, as such:

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    public function __construct($arg) {
        // Let the parent handle construction. 
        parent::__construct($arg); 
    }
}
```

What if, for some reason, the ParentClass needs to change to take more than one optional argument, which I would like my Child class to provide "just in case"? Unless I re-code the ChildClass, it will only ever take the one argument to the constructor, and will only ever pass that one argument.

Is this so rare or such a bad practice that the usual case is that a ChildClass wouldn't need to be inheriting from a ParentClass that takes different arguments?

Essentially, I've seen in Python where you can pass a potentially unknown number of arguments to a function via `somefunction(*args)` where 'args' is an array/iterable of some kind. **Does something like this exist in PHP?** Or should I refactor these classes before proceeding?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is something like this in php, though a bit verbose:

```
$args = func_get_args();
call_user_func_array(array($this, 'parent::__construct'), $args);
```

Comment: This causes an infinite loop on PHP 5.4.14

Comment: In 5.5 (maybe earlier) you can just do: `call_user_func_array('parent::__construct', func_get_args());`;

Comment: @ogc-nick I just tried it on versions 5.2 thru 5.6 with success.

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43377350/682673) for how to do this without `call_user_func_array()` in PHP 5.6 and up.

Answer (score 69):

This can be done in PHP >= 5.6 without `call_user_func_array()` by using the [`...` (splat) operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat):

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct(...func_get_args());
}
```

Comment: But why wouldn't you make `__construct()` [variadic](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics) to avoid having to call `func_get_args()`? E.g. `public function __construct(...$args) { parent::__construct(...$args); }`

Comment: @miken32 You could do that, but you lose the ability to typehint your parameters.

Answer (score 10):

if you get php nested limit error, try this:

```
$args = func_get_args();
call_user_func_array(array('parent', '__construct'), $args);
```

Answer (score 8):

My way of doing it (tested in PHP 7.1):

```
class ParentClass {
    public function __construct(...$args) {
        print 'Parent: ' . count($args) . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    public function __construct(...$args) {
        parent::__construct(...$args);
        print 'Child: ' . count($args). PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$child = new ChildClass(1, 2, 3, new stdClass);

//Output: 
//Parent: 4
//Child: 4
```

Test it https://3v4l.org/csJ68

In this case, the parent and the child have the same constructor signature.
It also works if you want to unpack your arguments in the parent constructor:

```
class ParentClass {
    public function __construct($a, $b, $c, $d = null) {
        print 'Parent: ' . $a .  $b .  $c . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    public function __construct(...$args) {
        parent::__construct(...$args);
    }
}

$child = new ChildClass(1, 2, 3);

//Output: Parent: 123
```

Test it https://3v4l.org/JGE1A

It is also worth noticing that in PHP >= 5.6 you can enforce types for variadic functions (scalar types in PHP >= 7):

```
class ParentClass {
    public function __construct(DateTime ...$args) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out these functions on php.net:

```
func_get_args
func_num_args
```

Also, if you want to make an optional argument, you can do this:

```
class ParentClass {
    function __construct($arg, $arg2="Default Value") {
        // Initialize a/some variable(s) based on $arg
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question : how do you call the parent constructor with a dynamic array of parameters.
You can NOT just do `parent::__construct(func_get_args())`

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, it's pretty bad practice to make a child class that uses different constructor arguments from the parent.  Especially in a language like PHP where it's poorly supported.

Of course, the generic way to pass a set of "whatever arguments we might ever want" in PHP is to pass a single argument consisting of an array of configuration values.

Comment: Of course, there you have the "Magic Container" code smell (http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MagicContainer). What you need is a Parameter Object (http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ParameterObject).

Comment: The magic container is unfortunately widely used in php applications, nonetheless.

Comment: The OP is asking about a situation where the **parent** class adds new constructor arguments. It's not about changing arguments in the child class. A solution to this problem would be useful if you have additional initialization logic in the child constructor so you have to call the parent's constructor (which may change its argument list).

Answer (score -6):

```
parent::__construct( func_get_args() );
```

Comment: Hm, does _not_ keep arguments in order (just throws them into an array in the first argument).